# Extremely slow internet on my laptop only: how to debug

Tags: networking, laptop

Since a few days, my connection is extremely slow on my laptop, but on all the other devices (phone, tablet, the computer of other people in the flat), the connection is really fast, for instance on my phone I reach 62Mbps on speedtest on wifi while my computer can't even start the test…

I have the feeling that what takes time is the first connection: for instance I can play a video fluently, but the video may take 40 seconds to start. Just doing a simple search on google may timeout, need multiple refresh, or take like 40 seconds to complete.

I have the feeling that the connection is also slower in other places (at my job), even if I use ethernet, but it is slightly better.

Even a ping make take between 20 seconds and 40 seconds to start (then it works fluently), see e.g. this gif that shows the connection to ping:

[image]

I tought that maybe sometimes I'm not even connected to the wifi, but a connection can timeout while a ping may work fine. For instance I tried to manually connect to various DNS servers, sometimes the connection works, sometimes it times out, but a ping may work at the same time:

[image]

Often, if I try to use `curl` to contact a website, the first tries time out, then I manage to reach the website in maybe 10 to 40 seconds, then the next tries are close to instantaneous:

```
$ time curl -vvv wordreference.com
* Could not resolve host: wordreference.com
* Closing connection 0
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: wordreference.com

real    0m20,063s
user    0m0,013s
sys     0m0,015s

[leo@bestos:/tmp]$ time curl -vvv wordreference.com
*   Trying 23.111.171.90:80...
* Connected to wordreference.com (23.111.171.90) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: wordreference.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.82.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 307 Moved Temporarily
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Location: https://wordreference.com/
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Date: Sat, 16 Jul 2022 12:33:15 GMT
< Content-Length: 149
< 
<head><title>Document Moved</title></head>
* Connection #0 to host wordreference.com left intact
<body><h1>Object Moved</h1>This document may be found <a HREF="https://wordreference.com/">here</a></body>
real    0m7,620s
user    0m0,002s
sys     0m0,006s

[leo@bestos:/tmp]$ time curl -vvv wordreference.com
*   Trying 23.111.171.90:80...
* Connected to wordreference.com (23.111.171.90) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: wordreference.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.82.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 307 Moved Temporarily
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Location: https://wordreference.com/
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Date: Sat, 16 Jul 2022 12:34:15 GMT
< Content-Length: 149
< 
<head><title>Document Moved</title></head>
* Connection #0 to host wordreference.com left intact
<body><h1>Object Moved</h1>This document may be found <a HREF="https://wordreference.com/">here</a></body>
real    0m0,534s
user    0m0,007s
sys     0m0,004s
```

Any idea what's going on an how to debug?

**EDIT**

Some outputs:

```
$ ethtool -i wlo1
driver: iwlwifi
version: 5.15.34
firmware-version: 46.fae53a8b.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-
expansion-rom-version: 
bus-info: 0000:00:14.3
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: no
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: no
supports-priv-flags: no

$  ethtool -S wlo1
NIC statistics:
     rx_packets: 24159
     rx_bytes: 4978806
     rx_duplicates: 0
     rx_fragments: 14403
     rx_dropped: 1033
     tx_packets: 28686
     tx_bytes: 4701596
     tx_filtered: 0
     tx_retry_failed: 0
     tx_retries: 683
     sta_state: 4
     txrate: 866700000
     rxrate: 6000000
     signal: 200
     channel: 0
     noise: 18446744073709551615
     ch_time: 18446744073709551615
     ch_time_busy: 18446744073709551615
     ch_time_ext_busy: 18446744073709551615
     ch_time_rx: 18446744073709551615
     ch_time_tx: 18446744073709551615

$ sudo ethtool -t wlo1
[sudo] Mot de passe de leo : 
Cannot test: Operation not supported
```

```
$ ifconfig -a
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
          inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:172.17.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0  TX bytes:0

eno2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr C0:3E:BA:68:12:04
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:349934 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:75634 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:480290990  TX bytes:10218206
          Interrupt:16 Memory:91300000-91320000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:209505 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:209505 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:942671302  TX bytes:942671302

vboxnet0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0A:XX:XX:XX:XX
          inet addr:192.168.56.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0  TX bytes:0

wlo1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:XX:XX:XX:XX
          inet addr:192.168.1.103  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:273938 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:189602 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:202163249  TX bytes:35610665
```

```
$ journalctl -f
juil. 16 19:35:00 me wpa_supplicant[2933]: wlo1: SME: Trying to authenticate with XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (SSID='TMNL-XXXXX' freq=2437 MHz)
juil. 16 19:35:00 me kernel: wlo1: authenticate with XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
juil. 16 19:35:00 me kernel: wlo1: send auth to XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (try 1/3)
juil. 16 19:35:00 me kernel: wlo1: authenticated
juil. 16 19:35:00 me wpa_supplicant[2933]: wlo1: Trying to associate with XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (SSID='TMNL-XXXXX' freq=2437 MHz)
juil. 16 19:35:00 me kernel: wlo1: associate with XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (try 1/3)
juil. 16 19:35:00 me wpa_supplicant[2933]: RRM: Ignoring radio measurement request: Not associated
juil. 16 19:35:00 me kernel: wlo1: RX AssocResp from XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (capab=0x1811 status=0 aid=1)
juil. 16 19:35:00 me kernel: wlo1: associated
juil. 16 19:35:00 me wpa_supplicant[2933]: wlo1: Associated with XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
juil. 16 19:35:00 me wpa_supplicant[2933]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
juil. 16 19:35:00 me wpa_supplicant[2933]: wlo1: WPA: Key negotiation completed with XX:XX:XX:XX:XX [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
juil. 16 19:35:00 me wpa_supplicant[2933]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to XX:XX:XX:XX:XX completed [id=0 id_str=]
juil. 16 19:35:00 me kernel: wlo1: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
juil. 16 19:35:00 me kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlo1: link becomes ready
juil. 16 19:35:01 me wpa_supplicant[2933]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-47 noise=9999 txrate=1000
juil. 16 19:35:01 me avahi-daemon[2326]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlo1.IPv6 with address fe80::7daa:a308:7ba8:7a8d.
juil. 16 19:35:01 me avahi-daemon[2326]: New relevant interface wlo1.IPv6 for mDNS.
juil. 16 19:35:01 me avahi-daemon[2326]: Registering new address record for fe80::7daa:a308:7ba8:7a8d on wlo1.*.
juil. 16 19:35:01 me wpa_supplicant[2933]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-47 noise=9999 txrate=1000
juil. 16 19:35:01 me wpa_supplicant[2933]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-47 noise=9999 txrate=300000
juil. 16 19:35:01 me avahi-daemon[2326]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlo1.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.103.
juil. 16 19:35:01 me avahi-daemon[2326]: New relevant interface wlo1.IPv4 for mDNS.
juil. 16 19:35:01 me avahi-daemon[2326]: Registering new address record for 192.168.1.103 on wlo1.IPv4.
juil. 16 19:35:02 me nscd[320562]: 320562 monitored file `/etc/resolv.conf` was written to
juil. 16 19:35:02 me systemd[1]: Stopping Name Service Cache Daemon...
juil. 16 19:35:02 me avahi-daemon[2326]: Got SIGHUP, reloading.
juil. 16 19:35:02 me avahi-daemon[2326]: Failed to read /etc/avahi/services.
juil. 16 19:35:02 me systemd[1]: nscd.service: Deactivated successfully.
juil. 16 19:35:02 me systemd[1]: Stopped Name Service Cache Daemon.
juil. 16 19:35:02 me systemd[1]: Starting Name Service Cache Daemon...
[...]
juil. 16 19:35:26 bestos wpa_supplicant[2933]: wlo1: WNM: Preferred List Available
juil. 16 19:35:26 bestos wpa_supplicant[2933]: wlo1: SME: Trying to authenticate with YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY (SSID='TMNL-XXXXX' freq=5320 MHz)
juil. 16 19:35:26 bestos kernel: wlo1: disconnect from AP 08:26:97:54:b9:31 for new auth to YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY
juil. 16 19:35:26 bestos kernel: wlo1: authenticate with YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY
juil. 16 19:35:26 bestos kernel: wlo1: send auth to YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY (try 1/3)
juil. 16 19:35:26 bestos wpa_supplicant[2933]: wlo1: Trying to associate with YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY (SSID='TMNL-XXXXX' freq=5320 MHz)
juil. 16 19:35:26 bestos kernel: wlo1: authenticated
juil. 16 19:35:26 bestos kernel: wlo1: associate with YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY (try 1/3)
juil. 16 19:35:26 bestos kernel: wlo1: RX ReassocResp from YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY (capab=0x1931 status=0 aid=4)
juil. 16 19:35:26 bestos kernel: wlo1: associated
juil. 16 19:35:26 bestos wpa_supplicant[2933]: wlo1: Associated with YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY
juil. 16 19:35:26 bestos wpa_supplicant[2933]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
juil. 16 19:35:26 bestos wpa_supplicant[2933]: wlo1: WPA: Key negotiation completed with YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
juil. 16 19:35:26 bestos wpa_supplicant[2933]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY completed [id=0 id_str=]
juil. 16 19:35:26 bestos wpa_supplicant[2933]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-52 noise=9999 txrate=866700
```

```
$ dmesg
[...]
[75163.268256] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eno2: NIC Link is Down
[75163.361617] wlo1: deauthenticating from YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[75164.292364] PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
[75167.366280] Filesystems sync: 3.073 seconds
[75167.472136] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.004 seconds) done.
[75167.476994] OOM killer disabled.
[75167.476997] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[75167.478774] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[75167.521410] e1000e: EEE TX LPI TIMER: 00000011
[75167.521604] intel_pch_thermal 0000:00:12.0: CPU-PCH is cool [40C], continue to suspend
[75167.814323] ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
[84861.175306] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
[84861.522196] ata1: SATA link down (SStatus 4 SControl 300)
[84861.715454] OOM killer enabled.
[84861.715458] Restarting tasks ... done.
[84861.724506] mei_hdcp 0000:00:16.0-b638ab7e-94e2-4ea2-a552-d1c54b627f04: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_hdcp_component_ops [i915])
[84861.848838] PM: suspend exit
[84862.097624] mmc0: cannot verify signal voltage switch
[84865.273312] wlo1: authenticate with XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
[84865.277307] wlo1: send auth to XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (try 1/3)
[84865.357673] wlo1: authenticated
[84865.359223] wlo1: associate with XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (try 1/3)
[84865.366324] wlo1: RX AssocResp from XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (capab=0x1811 status=0 aid=4)
[84865.393972] wlo1: associated
[84865.394618] wlo1: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
[84865.546047] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlo1: link becomes ready
[84893.182988] wlo1: disconnect from AP XX:XX:XX:XX:XX for new auth to YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY
[84893.223792] wlo1: authenticate with YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY
[84893.233310] wlo1: send auth to YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY (try 1/3)
[84893.273269] wlo1: authenticated
[84893.274247] wlo1: associate with YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY (try 1/3)
[84893.277461] wlo1: RX ReassocResp from YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY (capab=0x1931 status=0 aid=5)
[84893.279782] wlo1: associated
[85644.190759] kio_file.so[212217]: segfault at 9dd6 ip 0000000000009dd6 sp 00007ffffb273520 error 14 in kio_file.so[7f861c696000+9000]
[85644.190793] Code: Unable to access opcode bytes at RIP 0x9dac.
[85644.267067] kio_file.so[212220]: segfault at 9dd6 ip 0000000000009dd6 sp 00007fffbb4fa680 error 14 in kio_file.so[7f04d79e8000+9000]
[85644.267129] Code: Unable to access opcode bytes at RIP 0x9dac.
[85644.327964] kio_file.so[212223]: segfault at 9dd6 ip 0000000000009dd6 sp 00007ffd2ab44c50 error 14 in kio_file.so[7f0d8bc62000+9000]
[85644.327996] Code: Unable to access opcode bytes at RIP 0x9dac.
[85645.703837] kio_file.so[212365]: segfault at 9dd6 ip 0000000000009dd6 sp 00007ffda19c3990 error 14 in kio_file.so[7f60afc6b000+9000]
[85645.703870] Code: Unable to access opcode bytes at RIP 0x9dac.
[85645.795059] kio_file.so[212373]: segfault at 9dd6 ip 0000000000009dd6 sp 00007ffe6081c590 error 14 in kio_file.so[7f787358a000+9000]
[85645.795091] Code: Unable to access opcode bytes at RIP 0x9dac.
[85646.153270] kio_file.so[212500]: segfault at 9dd6 ip 0000000000009dd6 sp 00007ffc7cc4f5c0 error 14 in kio_file.so[7f5dfb45a000+9000]
[85646.153302] Code: Unable to access opcode bytes at RIP 0x9dac.
[85646.177202] kio_file.so[212502]: segfault at 9dd6 ip 0000000000009dd6 sp 00007ffcfe91d8d0 error 14 in kio_file.so[7f983e4b6000+9000]
[85646.177235] Code: Unable to access opcode bytes at RIP 0x9dac.
[85646.237502] kio_file.so[212508]: segfault at 9dd6 ip 0000000000009dd6 sp 00007ffe36b2f000 error 14 in kio_file.so[7f94b14d6000+9000]
[85646.237546] Code: Unable to access opcode bytes at RIP 0x9dac.
[87203.552924] kio_file.so[226296]: segfault at 9dd6 ip 0000000000009dd6 sp 00007fff0bb6e200 error 14 in kio_file.so[7f5b5f4b2000+9000]
[87203.552958] Code: Unable to access opcode bytes at RIP 0x9dac.
[87207.373304] ata1: SATA link down (SStatus 4 SControl 300)
[87207.853970] mmc0: cannot verify signal voltage switch
[88178.855710] kio_file.so[233290]: segfault at 9dd6 ip 0000000000009dd6 sp 00007ffdb6f9e5f0 error 14 in kio_file.so[7f905fc4f000+9000]
[88178.855746] Code: Unable to access opcode bytes at RIP 0x9dac.
[88971.292813] wlo1: Connection to AP YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY lost
[88972.452954] wlo1: authenticate with XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
[88972.457641] wlo1: send auth to XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (try 1/3)
[88972.515704] wlo1: authenticated
[88972.516536] wlo1: associate with XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (try 1/3)
[88972.535613] wlo1: RX AssocResp from XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (capab=0x1811 status=0 aid=1)
[88972.588594] wlo1: associated
[88972.589189] wlo1: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
[88985.820031] wlo1: disconnect from AP XX:XX:XX:XX:XX for new auth to YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY
[88985.853156] wlo1: authenticate with YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY
[88985.857673] wlo1: send auth to YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY (try 1/3)
[88985.897697] wlo1: authenticated
[88985.898317] wlo1: associate with YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY (try 1/3)
[88985.901845] wlo1: RX ReassocResp from YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY (capab=0x1931 status=0 aid=5)
[88985.904816] wlo1: associated
[93588.116168] wlo1: Connection to AP YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY lost
[93591.654810] wlo1: authenticate with XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
[93591.662042] wlo1: send auth to XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (try 1/3)
[93591.737139] wlo1: authenticated
[93591.737471] wlo1: associate with XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (try 1/3)
[93591.751915] wlo1: RX AssocResp from XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (capab=0x1811 status=0 aid=3)
[93591.809784] wlo1: associated
[93591.810100] wlo1: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
[95201.808512] wlo1: disconnect from AP XX:XX:XX:XX:XX for new auth to YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY
[95201.847343] wlo1: authenticate with YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY
[95201.852084] wlo1: send auth to YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY (try 1/3)
[95201.891955] wlo1: authenticated
[95201.892792] wlo1: associate with YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY (try 1/3)
[95201.895895] wlo1: RX ReassocResp from YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY (capab=0x1931 status=0 aid=3)
[95201.898679] wlo1: associated
[99826.829388] kio_file.so[317476]: segfault at 9dd6 ip 0000000000009dd6 sp 00007fffbdf18860 error 14 in kio_file.so[7fab6f2e7000+9000]
[99826.829402] Code: Unable to access opcode bytes at RIP 0x9dac.
[99927.893060] kio_file.so[318258]: segfault at 9dd6 ip 0000000000009dd6 sp 00007ffd39beabe0 error 14 in kio_file.so[7f4aa8839000+9000]
[99927.893088] Code: Unable to access opcode bytes at RIP 0x9dac.
[100223.140691] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eno2: NIC Link is Down
[100223.223514] wlo1: deauthenticating from YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[100224.877133] PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
[100225.273113] Filesystems sync: 0.395 seconds
[100225.377138] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.004 seconds) done.
[100225.381964] OOM killer disabled.
[100225.381965] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.016 seconds) done.
[100225.398729] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[100225.402910] e1000e: EEE TX LPI TIMER: 00000011
[100225.403302] intel_pch_thermal 0000:00:12.0: CPU-PCH is cool [50C], continue to suspend
[100225.712683] ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
[105465.198426] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
[105465.567672] ata1: SATA link down (SStatus 4 SControl 300)
[105465.742632] OOM killer enabled.
[105465.742635] Restarting tasks ... 
[105465.746020] mei_hdcp 0000:00:16.0-b638ab7e-94e2-4ea2-a552-d1c54b627f04: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_hdcp_component_ops [i915])
[105465.748821] done.
[105465.884713] PM: suspend exit
[105466.120846] mmc0: cannot verify signal voltage switch
[105469.353454] wlo1: authenticate with XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
[105469.356106] wlo1: send auth to XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (try 1/3)
[105469.445995] wlo1: authenticated
[105469.447582] wlo1: associate with XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (try 1/3)
[105469.457355] wlo1: RX AssocResp from XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (capab=0x1811 status=0 aid=1)
[105469.460320] wlo1: associated
[105469.651344] wlo1: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
[105469.651399] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlo1: link becomes ready
[105494.771838] wlo1: disconnect from AP XX:XX:XX:XX:XX for new auth to YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY
[105494.797834] wlo1: authenticate with YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY
[105494.801879] wlo1: send auth to YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY (try 1/3)
[105494.843649] wlo1: authenticated
[105494.845329] wlo1: associate with YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY (try 1/3)
[105494.848598] wlo1: RX ReassocResp from YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY (capab=0x1931 status=0 aid=4)
[105494.851004] wlo1: associated
```

```
$ systemctl status wpa_supplicant.service 
● wpa_supplicant.service - WPA supplicant
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant.service; linked; vendor preset: enabled)
                Active: active (running) since Fri 2022-07-15 14:17:45 CEST; 1 day 5h ago
                Main PID: 2933 (wpa_supplicant)
                IP: 0B in, 0B out
                IO: 0B read, 0B written
                Tasks: 1 (limit: 18958)
                Memory: 3.1M
                CPU: 28.712s
                CGroup: /system.slice/wpa_supplicant.service
                └─2933 /nix/store/c6ylr22mswvxww61rz98jw3pf7az3q39-wpa_supplicant-2.10/sbin/wpa_supplicant -u

                juil. 16 19:35:26 bestos wpa_supplicant[2933]: wlo1: WNM: Preferred List Available
                juil. 16 19:35:26 bestos wpa_supplicant[2933]: wlo1: SME: Trying to authenticate with YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY (SSID='TMNL-XXXXX' freq=5320 MHz)
                juil. 16 19:35:26 bestos wpa_supplicant[2933]: wlo1: Trying to associate with YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY (SSID='TMNL-XXXXX' freq=5320 MHz)
                juil. 16 19:35:26 bestos wpa_supplicant[2933]: wlo1: Associated with YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY
                juil. 16 19:35:26 bestos wpa_supplicant[2933]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
                juil. 16 19:35:26 bestos wpa_supplicant[2933]: wlo1: WPA: Key negotiation completed with YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
                juil. 16 19:35:26 bestos wpa_supplicant[2933]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY completed [id=0 id_str=]
                juil. 16 19:35:26 bestos wpa_supplicant[2933]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-52 noise=9999 txrate=866700
                juil. 16 19:36:54 bestos wpa_supplicant[2933]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-57 noise=9999 txrate=780000
                juil. 16 19:43:31 bestos wpa_supplicant[2933]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-54 noise=9999 txrate=866700
```

**EDIT**

I also tried to boot another system (xubuntu 20.04), and it is similarly slow, so I guess it's not something really specific to my own configuration (I'm running NixOs unstable). On the other hand, if I connect to my phone configured as a hotspot, it is quick, so it seems that the problem is not my hardware… Also, I experience a similar slow internet on ethernet (at my job).

Note also that I was expecting ping to lose many packets when it is super slow, but in fact it does not drop any packet… each packet is obtained reasonably quickly (10ms apparently), but then it waits maybe 5 seconds before sending the next packet (instead of 1 second):

[image]

(note that in this example the first line appeared directly (maybe it was cached), sometimes it also takes a few seconds to appear)

some people asked me about my `resolve.conf`, so here is the one at my job when I'm using ethernet (I added `8.8.8.8` via networkmanager as a DNS server to try to improve the speed, but seems like it's not better), I can also send the one at home later today:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Generated by resolvconf
search wlan.MYLAB.nl
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 192.168.1.1
options edns0
```

Comment: Your WiFi module might be malfunctioning. Check `dmesg` for anything unusual.

Comment: Any difference depending on power supply mode ? Output of ifconfig -a ?

Comment: Also check your wifi protected access supplicant logs. Check which band (2.4 vs 5Ghz) your laptop uses and compare with other devices. Also channels within those bands.

Comment: @MC68020 Thanks for your answer! No, it is slow in both battery mode and when it's plugged. I added the output in the edited question.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Thanks for the answer! I can't see anything particularly wrong in `dmesg`, except maybe `CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-47 noise=9999 txrate=1000` but I'm not sure what it means. I added the corresponding log in the edited question.

Comment: Well, I cannot yet tell how it could be related but there is actually something really wrong told by your dmesg. Kio_file segfaulting. Running KDE-Plasma I presume. Which version (plasma & frameworks) ?

Comment: Try adding `pcie_aspm.policy=performance` to your kernel boot parameters and see if it helps. If it doesn't I've no clue.

Comment: Slowness in establishing connections while speed is fine once the connection is established, might be something as simple as a bad nameserver (often in `/etc/resolv.conf`).

Comment: @MC68020 I'm using NixOs unstable 1ffba9f2f68 but the same issue also arrives in livecd (tested on xubuntu 20.04) so I don't think it's related to KDE. And I also don't think it's too much of a hardware issue, as the same problem occurs in some network via ethernet instead of wifi, and if I use my phone's wifi instead of my flat's wifi, the problem is gone.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Thanks. I tried, but can't see any change…

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity His ping output shows that's clearly not the case.

Comment: @tobiasBora There are many things that could override the assigned DNS servers. Check if your computers are actually using such addresses using leak detection sites (e.g. https://ipleak.net/). In some routers, it is also possible to set DNS servers if you don't want to keep relying on your ISP for DNS resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get information off you Wifi card from `ethtool -i DEV_NAME` for me it would be `ethtool -i wlan0`. You can also run `man ethtool` to see all of the other options like driver, test, and a lot more. It basically allows you to choose/set all of the options that would be under **Advanced Wireless Options**, then the **Properties** of your wifi card, if you were on Windows.

Comment: Thanks! So I added the outputs above, but I'm not sure how to interpret it. Regarding the tests, apparently my card is not compatible with that.

Comment: Also, I tried to use my phone as a wifi spot and in that case it seems to work fine… so I'm not sure if the problem is really a hardware issue.